# Live Edit Twig templates with phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to setup Live Editing in Phpstorm with Twig templates? I know I can with html pages but it doesn't allow me to select my index.html.twig template.

Note: I am not using the symphony framework. Just twig templates.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I follow you... You can't directly open .twig files in browser, but Live Edit does work for them. I have a .php file that renders twig using

```
echo $twig->render()
```

I create a javascript debug run configuration, specifying my php page URL (`http://localhost/twig_test/index.php`) as `URL`, press `Debug`, then start editing my .twig file => page is updated on-the-fly

Comment: I have it setup now debug the index.php page but now the server is not serving out the external js/css pages.

Comment: what PHPStorm version do you use? What is Live Edit plugin version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some file watchers ([gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)) that will reload page after twig templates will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found gulp an easy way to do this. There is a tutorial that explains it well: https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-theming-with-gulp-again/ You just need the browser sync part, but the rest may be useful for you.
This includes clearing the whole cache which is not needed if you set up the render cache properly according to: https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374 
As a bonus, I've found [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) to be really useful since you don't need to enable xdebug, but can explore a variable eg {{ dd(node) }} which runs really fast.
This solution does not need phpstorm but works very well. Just type, save and presto the browser(s) auto reload with your changes.